# Lenovo laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 is not booting after low storage warning

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, hard-drive, lenovo

I've been running Ubuntu 22.04 in a Lenovo laptop for a couple of months now, and I got a low storage warning yesterday. A few hours later I tried to copy a file into a USB storage device, and for some reason it was not letting me do it. After that the laptop froze, and I was forced to restart the computer using the power button. After that the Lenovo and Ubuntu logo appeared, but now it just hangs and doesn't properly boot.

I am still able to boot into grub and I was able to discover my main hard drive only has 400kb of free storage space left. I remembered I had a similar issue whit Ubuntu 22.04 when I was running it in a VM, so I tried to fix it by booting into recovery mode and using the clean option, which did something, but didn't actually fix the issue. Is there a way I can copy the contents of my hard Drive into a USB using grub or is there a way I can delete files through grub? I also tried accessing my hard drive by using my Ubuntu installation USB
by opening the terminal running inside the USB, but for some reason it asks for a user and a password and when I give it it just denies it, even after adding a second sudo user through the root terminal in Ubuntu Recovery mode.

---

UPDATE: I logged into root with ubuntu's recovery mode and I was able to find the path to my main hard drive by using "find /" and I tried to mout my usb
to copy my files  but it gave me the following error "mount: [name of the directory im going to mount to]: unknown filesystem type 'hfsplus'". Do I need to add an argument to mount the usb drive. Because I had no problem mounting back when the computer worked fine

Comment: Hfsplus is an Apple file system for whatever that tells you.